# Connections to a DB: what are some of the best practices and standards?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, database-connection

I am writing an API that connects to a Mysql database. My Model layer shares one connection I declare in a Node.js module. like this

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});
export connection;
```

then I require it and use it as necessary. I am new to the world of actually implementing these kind of connections, as previously I mostly did design for the backend and developed on the front end. I see that some people use Pools, I am not certain what these are for, and what the benefits are. I feel like there is some downside to sharing one connection, and also downsides to creating connections as necessary. If anyone has any tips, or related readings, I'd be grateful

Thank so much,

Sammy

Comment: The general idea of a pool is to simultaneously be able to achieve multiple objectives, like... create as many connections as necessary, while creating and holding open as few connections as possible, creating new connections as seldom as practical, automatically reusing connections as often as feasible... sort of the solution to some of the problems you're contemplating.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure this question is a good candidate here, since we don't do tutoral recommendations and the topic is very broad.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the answer! So, generally, in a pool I specify the number of connections, trying to keep it as low as possible but allowing for the completion of multiple objectives, stay, being able to read from the database with a second connection while the first is busy?